# Assigning values to a variable during recursion

Tags: recursion, dart

So I have a list (`[123,487693821,1234,[111,222,[10,20],[11,45],34,21],333,[67,67],546]`), and a basic recursive function that prints the list in a formatted way so as to indent whenever there is a list inside a list and show what level the list is, like so:

```
0 123
0 487693821
0 1234
1   111
1   222
2       10
2       20
2       11
2       45
1   34
1   21
0 333
1   67
1   67
0 546
```

The code to do this is:

```dart
listPrinter(list,[lev=0,ind=''])
{
    for(var e in list)
    {
        if(e is List) listPrinter(e,lev+1,ind+'\t');
        else print('$lev $ind$e');
    }
}
```

My question is, what happens during recursion when I change `lev+1` to something like `lev++`, or `++lev`. I have the output for each scenario, which I'll post below, but I don't know why I get the output I do. I don't know how to trace what's happening in the recursive calls. Note that the only thing I change is `lev`, so the indentation is still correct in the output below.

Output when 'lev + 1' is changed to `lev++`. As you can see the level doesn't even change until the second list on the `2` level (reference first output), then does some wacky stuff at the end there.

```
0 123
0 487693821
0 1234
0   111
0   222
0       10
0       20
1       11
1       45
2   34
2   21
1 333
1   67
1   67
2 546
```

Output when `lev + 1` is changed to `++lev`. This method is correct until it hits the second list in the `2` level(again, reference the first output I posted), when it then starts to do some crazy stuff I can't understand.

```
0 123
0 487693821
0 1234
1   111
1   222
2       10
2       20
3       11
3       45
3   34
3   21
1 333
2   67
2   67
2 546
```

I know this is complex, but really it just comes down to what happens when variables are assigned in recursion, postcrements, and precrements. The language it's written in is dart, but I can probably write it in python or java if that would be easier. Thanks.

**Clarification:** I understand that `lev + 1` is different from `++lev` and `lev++` in that it doesn't actually assign a value to lev. What I want to know is what's happening during the recursive process when I do assign `lev` to a new value, and why it's different for a postcrement and precrement.

Comment: what language is this question about?

Comment: I believe the question is language agnostic, and has more to do with the semantics of recursion, but the language it's written in is dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your function have an integer defined called `lev`

By default (in your first function call) the value of `lev` is `0`

Now in the context of the function you call a function (the same function actually, but that doesn't really matter).

When you call it like this

```
func(lev+1)
```

The function will be called with argument value `lev+1` and after the function returns the value of `lev` is unchanged within the context of the calling function.

When you call it like this

```
func(lev++)
```

The function will be called with argument value `lev` and after the function returns the value of `lev` is `lev+1` within the context of the calling function. The `++`-part is called the **post-increment operator** since it increments the value of your variable **after** the call has been made

When you call it like this

```
func(++lev)
```

The function will be called with argument value `lev+1` and after the function returns the value of `lev` is `lev+1` within the context of the calling function. The `++`-part is called the **pre-increment operator** since it increments the value of your variable **before** the call has been made

Now the fact that you use it in a recursive situation can confuse the matter a bit.

You have to understand that each function call will define `lev` to be used within that context. Since you use recursion, there will be several variables `lev` next to each other, each in their own function context

Answer (score 0):

lev++ or ++lev means that lev's value will be actualized. It's the same as

```
lev = lev + 1;
```

lev + 1 only returns value of lev + 1 leaving variable lev unchanged.

The difference between lev++ and ++lev is that former one raises it's value after the assignment or use of variable while latter one will do so before it's use.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between:

`someFn(lev + 1)` and `someFn(++lev)` or `someFn(lev++)` is that the latter two are actually changing the value of `lev` in the middle of the loop you're in. The first one doesn't modify the value.